# Where does Java language define if a Throwable is checked or not?

Tags: java, exception

Both Exception and RuntimeException inherits from Throwable and do not implement any interface to tell whether they are checkd or not.

Where is it specified that Exception is checked and RuntimeException is unchecked? Is it hardwired in the language or the JVM?

Comment: check this thread 
[Java: checked vs unchecked exception explanation][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation

Comment: it is hardwired in the java language. the jvm is just a tool to keep check on those

Comment: **RuntimeException and all its subclasses are, collectively, the run-time exception classes.

The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.**

Comment: @vikeng21 The JVM has nothing to do with the checking of exceptions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's defined in the [Java Language Specification section 11.1.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.1.1).

> `Throwable` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the exception classes.
>
> `Exception` is the superclass of all the exceptions from which ordinary programs may wish to recover.
>
> `Error` is the superclass of all the exceptions from which ordinary programs are not ordinarily expected to recover.
>
> `Error` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the *error classes*.
>
> [...]
>
> The class `RuntimeException` is a direct subclass of `Exception`. `RuntimeException` is the superclass of all the exceptions which may be thrown for many reasons during expression evaluation, but from which recovery may still be possible.
>
> `RuntimeException` and all its subclasses are, collectively, the *run-time exception classes*.
>
> The unchecked exception classes are the run-time exception classes and the error classes.
>
> The checked exception classes are all exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes. That is, the checked exception classes are all subclasses of `Throwable` other than `RuntimeException` and its subclasses and `Error` and its subclasses.

Comment: The way it's written, it still leaves open whether `Throwable` itself is checked or not.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik `Throwable` is definitely not one of the "unchecked exception classes", so it must be checked as it is one of the "exception classes other than the unchecked exception classes"

Comment: Yes, you're right. Just the added explanation doesn't cover it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik indeed.  Once of those cases where the extra sentence added for clarification actually makes things less clear...